# MassTransit: How to configure retry policy for Send/Publish

Tags: masstransit

I am using MassTransit with Azure Service Bus and would like to configure a retry policy for Send/Publish.

The way I did it is:

````
    ```private void ConfigureUsingAzureServiceBus(IServiceCollectionConfigurator x)
    {
        x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ConfigurePublish(c =>
            {
                c.UseRetry(rc => rc.Interval(90, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
            });

            cfg.ConfigureSend(c =>
            {
                c.UseRetry(rc => rc.Interval(90, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
            });```
````

I am not sure if this is the right way because I get sometimes: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException and my message is not sent to the bus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MassTransit does not support a retry policy for Publish/Send.

For Azure Service Bus, the transport uses a retry policy under the hood with the Azure Service Bus .NET client library. If the exception is ultimately thrown, it's because the client library gave up.